# copy images anchor tag to images that have the same image SRC

Tags: jquery, image, tags, anchor, imagesource

I have a list item

```
<ul class="listWithAnchors">
  <li><a href="/link1"><img src="/path1.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="/link2"><img src="/path2.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="/link3"><img src="/path3.jpg" /></a></li>
<ul>

<ul class="listWithoutAnchors">
  <li><img src="/path2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/path1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/path3.jpg" /></li>
<ul>
```

I would like to use jQuery to wrap the images in the anchor tags that have matching src paths. So the end result should look like this:

```
<ul class="listWithoutAnchors">
  <li><a href="/link2"><img src="/path2.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="/link1"><img src="/path1.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="/link3"><img src="/path3.jpg" /></a></li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking something like this is what you're looking for?

First off we store the combined anchor URL and image src in an array by going through each list element in the list with anchors. And then we cycle through the other list and compare the src of the image of each list item to our array and if there is a match we take the URL also stored in that object where the src match occurred.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var someArray = new array()
    $(".listWithAnchors li a").each(function(i){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var src = $("a",this).attr('src');
        someArray.push({"l":link,"s":src});
    });

    $(".listWithoutAnchors li").each(function(i){
        var othersrc = $("img",this).attr('src');
        for(var j=0;j<someArray.length;j++){
            if(someArray[j]["s"] == othersrc){
                $(this).html("<a href='"+someArray[j]["l"]+"'>"+$(this).html()+"</a>");
            }
        }
    }
});
```